# Merge all subarrays on second level of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, associative-array

I need to find a way to combine elements by key in a new array, such that I end up with just one key containing all values for that key (found elsewhere in the parent array). This will make more sense when you see the example below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AAA] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F104_f58f85f9dbbe1ce083ca09a6f9ace679
                    [1] => F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634
                    [2] => F104_d5fde0ad2499052e0eae6dec451f9385
                )

            [BBB] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F44_e2e052e7b78abbae02ffcf7413302a0c
                    [1] => F44_4d4da736509babebba7433b203b16753
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [AAA] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634
                )

            [ZZZ] => Array
                (
                    [0] => F20_5e742bc21f41a14243c3f72b9fa4815e
                )
        )
)
```

The original array is quite large with more keys and values. But everything is in the same structure depicted above.

I'd like to read that in, and return

```
    Array
    (
        [AAA] => Array
            (
                [0] => F104_f58f85f9dbbe1ce083ca09a6f9ace679
                [1] => F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634
                [2] => F104_d5fde0ad2499052e0eae6dec451f9385
                [4] => F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634
            )

        [BBB] => Array
            (
                [0] => F44_e2e052e7b78abbae02ffcf7413302a0c
                [1] => F44_4d4da736509babebba7433b203b16753
            )
        [ZZZ] => Array
            (
                [0] => F20_5e742bc21f41a14243c3f72b9fa4815e
            )
    )
```

What's the least painful and most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `array_merge_recursive()` and array unpacking to pass the separate parts into it...

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive(...$array));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [AAA] => Array
        (
            [0] => F104_f58f85f9dbbe1ce083ca09a6f9ace679
            [1] => F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634
            [2] => F104_d5fde0ad2499052e0eae6dec451f9385
            [3] => F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634
        )

    [BBB] => Array
        (
            [0] => F44_e2e052e7b78abbae02ffcf7413302a0c
            [1] => F44_4d4da736509babebba7433b203b16753
        )

    [ZZZ] => Array
        (
            [0] => F20_5e742bc21f41a14243c3f72b9fa4815e
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) to traverse the parent array. And use another `foreach` loop to combine the values. Please note the `$output` array is passed by reference.

```
$inputArray = [
    0 => [
        'AAA' => [
            0 => 'F104_f58f85f9dbbe1ce083ca09a6f9ace679',
            1 => 'F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634',
            2 => 'F104_d5fde0ad2499052e0eae6dec451f9385',
        ],
        'BBB' => [
            0 => 'F44_e2e052e7b78abbae02ffcf7413302a0c',
            1 => 'F44_4d4da736509babebba7433b203b16753',
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        'AAA' => [
            0 => 'F104_480e9f231b2b5a138f8aa5570ffa8634'
        ],
        'ZZZ' => [
            0 => 'F20_5e742bc21f41a14243c3f72b9fa4815e'
        ]
    ]
];
$output = [];
array_map(function($values) use (&$output){
    foreach ($values as $key => $value){
        if(empty($output[$key])){
            $output[$key] = $value;
        }else{
            $output[$key] = array_merge($output[$key], $value);
        }
    }
}, $inputArray);
print_r($output);
```

Here is a working example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97909ce93184fad6c33af8eb48d184ae86438774